# Почему так мало разрешений у WebPack

Tags: webpack, sass, less, pug

Кто в курсе почему webpack конвертирует из js в js? Почему можно только с Sass работать? Есть ли какой то скрипт  помогающий работать  с less и  Pug ?
[image: Почему так мало разрешений?]

Comment: Потому что все существующие расширения в эту картинку просто не влезут. Работайте с чем хотите.

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, жаль что создатели WebPack вводят в заблуждение подобными картинками, нужно давать полную информацию а не лишь часть(

Comment: WebPack сам по себе не делает ничего. Поддержка всех расширений реализуется сторонними плагинами. Если поддержки какого-то расширения вам не хватает — вы всегда сможете написать нужный плагин самостоятельно. Плагинов существуют тысячи, и помещать их полный список в эту картинку было бы крайне глупо.

Comment: Нужно не на картинки любоваться, а читать документацию.

Comment: @andreymal к сожалению документация на английском( там ничего не понятно

Comment: Нужно учить английский, без этого в современной разработке делать нечего.

Comment: @andreymal понял,извините за беспокойство, и правда в разработке мне делать нечего(